# python cv2 puttext - error while showing the variable

Tags: python, image, text, opencv

I'm writing one of my first codes and I want to show variable on image. Variable is read from textfile.
Here is part of my code:

```
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale=2
fontColor=(255,255,255)
lineType=2;

def line11():
    cv2.ellipse(img, (443,350), (35,35), 0, 0, -180, (0,0,255), 4);
    cv2.putText(img, x,(443,320),fontScale, (255,255,255),lineType)
```

Reading value x from texfile:

```
with open('US1.txt') as f1, open('US2.txt') as f2: 
    for x, y in zip(f1,f2):
        x = x.strip()
        y = y.strip()
        print("{0} {1}".format(x, y))
```

Unfortunately, I got the error:

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-bc1d3b9f83c2> in <module>
    130 
    131         if (float(x) <=0.5):
--> 132             line11();
    133 
    134         elif (0.5< float(x)<=1):

<ipython-input-2-bc1d3b9f83c2> in line11()
     16     cv2.ellipse(img, (443,350), (35,35), 0, 0, -180, (0,0,255), 4);
     17 
---> 18     cv2.putText(img, x, (443,350),fontScale, (255,255,255),lineType)
     19 
     20 def line12():

TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

I can't find a solution. I tried many options (i.e chinging type of x), now I'm helpless. Can somebody explain it to me? 
Thank you!

Comment: try `color=(255, 255, 255)` in your call to `cv2.putText()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `font` argument. Try this:

```
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale=2
fontColor=(255,255,255)
lineType=cv2.line_AA
org=(443,320)
text = str(x)

cv2.putText(img, text,org,font,fontScale,fontColor,lineType)
```

Refer [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv.PutText)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is because you forgot to mention font on **putText** function. The tuple it got was (255,255,255), while it was expecting **fontScale**.

cv2.putText(image, text, org, font, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]])

Try:
    cv2.putText(img, x,(443,320),font, fontScale, fontColor,lineType)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't noticed that mistake!The simplest things are the hardest to find. :)

Comment: No worries, that is why we are a community. If you find difficulties along getting the parameters correct for a function, do try:

dir(package) => to view its function
help(package.functionName) => to view function definition

Example:
import os
dir(os)
help(os.listdir)